# calculate upcoming category based on the dates of the past categories

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have the above table structure in the database and I want to calculate the upcoming abbreviation for an id (if a particular abbreviation has an actual date present (achieved) then it should give the current_date(which will be upcoming date even if it's in past) and next upcoming abbreviation for that particular id): if the last abbreviation has an actual date (for which category is also present).

expected result:
[image]

I'm new to SQL, i guess it can be achieved by taking maximum of actual_date present for abbreviation for a id.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Note that your present structure is possibly sub-optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the abbreviation for each id with the maximum actual date, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by actual_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where actual_date is not null
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```